# .Net compability

Tags: iis-7

I was told that I need to migrate to a new server 2008 with IIS 7.

But the program was so old that the previous servor was in 2000 and the .Net Framework is 1.1

For IIS 7, .Net Framework is 3.5

I thought of installing both version. and installed .Net 1.1

But .Net 1.1 automatically uninstalled IIS 7.

I manually reinstalled IIS 7 but I can't change the default framework version to 1.1

Is there anyway to have both Framework in IIS 7?

Comment: Hi all, Tkz for the answers. It is already weekends for me. I will try again on MOnday and reply.. Tkz again.. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you create a website in IIS you assign it an Application Pool, when accessing the Advanced Settings (in IIS7) of the application pool you can select the framework version to use - this first drop down should allow you to select v1.1 if it is installed.

With it being IIS7, you might need to alter a couple of settings (for instance, I think you will need to set the Managed Pipeline Mode to "Classic" rather than "Integrated".) This should compensate for some of the differences of configuration - though, you may find conflicting problems down the line that can only be managed by manually changing your sites configuration file, or some other parts of the project itself that aren't compatible.

Comment: managed to install .Net 1.1 on IIS 7.manually specified a certain aspx page as a default document on web.config of the application.Now the error is 404.17 NOT FOUND, requested content is appeared to be script and will not be served by static file handler.needs to add at the feature service but 1.1 dun allow to use feature service.Need to edit at physical config file. Any idea how to do that?? Tkz..

Answer (score 1):

Check out:
http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/472/how-to-install-aspnet-11-with-iis7-on-vista-and-windows-2008/

Might help you

Answer (score 1):

I did a quick google search and found a blog about it. I'm not sure if its right but i hope this helps you

http://blogs.iis.net/bills/archive/2008/06/02/installing-asp-net-1-1-with-iis7-on-vista-and-windows-2008.aspx

Comment: Can i get a clarification as to why my answer and Law Metzler's answer got voted down? They specify exactly how to install .Net Framework 1.1 with IIS7. The question was "Is there anyway to have both Framework in IIS 7?" and these answer show how to install 1.1 without running into the uninstall problem the creator is having.